# Flash Rollover only on object and not transparent background

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I have a png-file with an object on it. I want my rollover effect to start when I am actually hovering over the object and not the transparent background. Is there any way to do this? I hope it's clear what I mean.

Comment: You can for example create a transparent object (a copy of your png's object) and add the rollover effect to it instead of that image ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In my case I have horse so I need Flash to do the rollover stuff only on the shape of this particular horse. Yes I know this sounds funny.

Comment: I meant, you can reproduce the shape of that "horse" as a MovieClip for example, make it transparent then put it over your original image and let it doing the rollover effect when it's hovering by the mouse ...

Comment: Alright so I tried that but Flash automatically gives it this little box around it and the rollover effect is just the same (applied when the mouse enters the box around the object)

Comment: I don't know how you did created that, but that should work ... take a look on this [very simple example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bAhpN.gif) ...

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Obviously I made a mistake then. How did you create the transparent object?

Comment: Take a copy of your image (the Bitmap) and break apart it then you can remove all unnecessary part with the eraser tool for example ...

Comment: If you edit your question to show your current rollover code, I'll give you an example on how to do this through code.   Breaking apart bitmaps can potentially really slow down your app (especially on mobile). unless it's a very simple shape (very few curves and points) I'd avoid that method.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue (described here: [Preventing the bounding box of transparent Bitmap Sprite from triggering mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959880/preventing-the-bounding-box-of-transparent-bitmap-sprite-from-triggering-mouse-e))

The code there to define a `hitarea` works well – but there s a problem if your bounding boxes overlap, which was my problem. If your images are far enough apart, that code should work.